# Computed that returns a sorted observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a computed observable that returns a filtered, sorted version of my `observableArray` but the sort is not working at all.

Here is [My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/BPBa7/2/)

```
String.prototype.contains = function (value) {
    return this.indexOf(value) != -1;
};

function Item(data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data);
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.items = ko.observableArray([new Item('John'), new Item('Pat')]);
    this.filterValue = ko.observable();

    this.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
        var filterValue = self.filterValue();

        if(!filterValue)
            return self.items();

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items(), function(){
            return item.name().toLowerCase().contains(filterValue.toLowerCase());
        }).sort(function(a,b){
            return a.name == b.name ? 0 : (a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1);
        });
    });
}
```

**THE ANSWER**
Here's the update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/BPBa7/10/)

Comment: You're not declaring and setting the "self" variable anywhere. *edit* oh, you are in the fiddle - it's discouraging when questions contain inaccurate code :(

Comment: fixed, sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Paul Manzotti noted, your sort function is not accessing the "name" properties correctly. In addition, your "filterValue" is `undefined`, so your function exits before it gets to the sort.

Something like this will make it work:

```
    var filtered = filterValue ? ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items(), function(item){
        return item.name().toLowerCase().contains(filterValue.toLowerCase());
    }) : self.items();

    return filtered.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.name() == b.name() ? 0 : (a.name() < b.name() ? -1 : 1);
    });
```

Comment: ok I see what I'm doing wrong, if `filterValue` doesn't have a value then I'm just returning the array which is not sorted, but if there is a `filterValue` then it's sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sort` function isn't calling observables correctly:

```
.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.name() == b.name() ? 0 : (a.name() < b.name() ? -1 : 1);
    })
```

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manzanotti/BPBa7/3/) too, and that appears to work.

Comment: The sorting is only done when a filter is applied in the question, so that's what I've implemented. Type a in the filter box, and Brandon will go before Pat.

Comment: Yes that's true; it's kind-of hard to tell what the OP wants :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I try to stick to the question asked! You're right though, I imagine they do want the whole thing sorted - given that it's more useful sorted when it's not filtered!

Comment: Yes, it should be sorted whenever the computed is read, which would be when it initially loads as well

Comment: ok I see what I'm doing wrong, if `filterValue` doesn't have a value then I'm just returning the array which is not sorted, but if there is a `filterValue` then it's sorted.